# Improper index matrix reference in parfor matlab called from command line

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have this piece of MATLAB code:

```
path(path,'./Classes');
locationID = 'Z8Ksof1rzm';
poolobj = gcp('nocreate');
if isempty(poolobj)
    parpool(4)
else
    %do nothing. we already have parpool running
end
myFiles = dir(strcat('./exportParse/exportLocation_', locationID));
MachineData = cell(length(myFiles)-2,1);
disp(myFiles)
parfor iFile =3:length(myFiles)
        jsonFile = myFiles(iFile).name;           
        MachineData{iFile-2} = loadjson(strcat('./exportParse/exportLocation_', locationID,'/',jsonFile));
end
```

The script runs pretty well from the MATLAB desktop. I see no errors and I get all 4 processors working on the json parsing. At the end, I get `MachineData` filled with the desired information. All good.

The problem occurs when I call

```
matlabPath="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r"
$matlabPath "run myScript.m"
```

where `myScript.m` is the file containing the code above. The script won't run again, it says this:

```
10x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum

Error using readDataAprocam (line 17)
Improper index matrix reference.

Error in run (line 63)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

as you can see, the line `dis(myFiles)` returns a valid struct array of files.

Line 17 is the line of the `parfor` command.

Note that on the shell and in MATLAB I'm located on the same path. I also shut down the parpool on the matlab desktop so the script running from the shell can claim it. there is no problem here as well.

What does `Improper index matrix reference` means on this context? Why does it run from the matlab desktop and not from the shell?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.3 and MATLAB 2014b.

Comment: Can you try it on the shell using a normal `for` loop? I don't expect it to solve the issue, but it typically returns better error messages.

Comment: What do You have on line 63? Maybe You can access `A(1,2)` element by `A(3)` (for A with size 2XN) in Matlab desktop but not from shell.

Comment: I've made some changes in the code, and now I'm getting another error. It seems that I solved this one but got sucked further. I'm going to post my "answer here" and make a new question with the next problem I'm facing. Btw @Daniel my new code runs with `for`, but not with `parfor`

Comment: @Crowley I think this error might be related to the function `run`. My script doesn't have more than 20 lines.

Comment: @otmezger Ah... I can see it now. Then one must find the path to the `run()` command. Or You can nest it into `try` `catch ME` envelope and display the error message in `ME`.

Comment: I failed to reproduce your issue. Could you try to simplify your code, maybe the same error can be produced using only a single json file without any folder structure?

Comment: Regarding the first line: `path(path,'./Classes');` Relative path on the search path don't work when you use cd. I typically end up using `addpath(genpath(pwd))` when navigated to the directory, then `savepath`. Maybe try it the same to eliminate a possible cause of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did, but I got rid of this error. My code looks like this now:

myScript.m:

```
%% settings
path(path,'./Classes');
locationID = 'Z8Ksof1rzm';
poolobj = gcp('nocreate');
if isempty(poolobj)
    parpool(4)
else
    %do nothing. we already have parpool running
end
%% get files
disp('ok. lets try it')
myFiles = dir(strcat('./exportParse/exportLocation_', locationID,'/export*'));
MachineData = cell(length(myFiles),1);

parfor iFile =1:length(myFiles)
    data = importJSONFile(iFile,locationID,myFiles);
    MachineData{iFile} =data;
end %looping over files
MachineData
```

Script importJSONFile:

```
function data = importJSONFile(fileIndex,locationID,myFiles)
  jsonFile = myFiles(fileIndex).name;
  filePath = strcat('./exportParse/exportLocation_', locationID,'/',jsonFile);
  data = loadjson(filePath);
  %data = struct;
end
```

The code runs from the shell ONLY if I change the `parfor` to `for`. if I leave the `parfor` it will trow the error

```
Error using myScript (line 16)
Conversion to char from cell is not possible.

Error in run (line 63)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Line 16 is the `parfor` line.

... but, I got rid of the error above.

Comment: What is the difference between `parfor` and `for` loops?

Comment: @Crowley: You can read the documentation for `parfor`, that's to much to answer in a short comment.